# useSelector not firing after change in redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working on an appication that I am using redux

I want to use useEffect to load data when the page opens and log the data to store

but useSelector does not change when data in store changes

I fetch the data from an api and dispatch it to the redux store and use useSelector the get the dispatched values. the useEffect dispatches the data to the store but useSelector does not pickup the values after the change

Category

```
 const categorys = useSelector(state => state.category.category)

useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
   
    listCategory()
    .then(res => {
        dispatch({
            type: "LIST_CATEGORIES",
            payload: res.data.data
        })
        setLoading(false)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        if (err.response) {
            // Request made and server responded
            toast.error(err.response.data.error)
            toast.error(err.response.data.name)
            toast.error(err.response.data.email)
            toast.error(err.response.data.password)
            toast.error(err.response.data.username)

          } else if (err.request) {
            // The request was made but no response was received
            console.log(err.request);

          } else {
            // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
            console.log('Error', err.message);

          }
        setLoading(false)
    })
}, [])
```

reducer

```
const initialState = {
    category:[
      
    ],
    current: null

}
export const categoryReducer = (state = initialState, action) =>{
    switch(action.type){
        case "LIST_CATEGORIES":
            return {
                ...state,
                ...action.payload
            };

        default:
            return state
    }
};
```

Data from api

res.data.data = [{
_id: "ksdj9dsfj",
name: "monitor",
description: "It is used to view what is on the system"
}]

Comment: Does this `res.data.data` value actually contain a field named `category` ?  If not, you're not going to update the existing array, so it will never re-render.

Comment: yes it has array of json which is dispatched to redux store @marikerikson

Comment: In that case the component _should_ be re-rendering.

I would recommending reviewing the structure of the data coming back from the server to make sure that it really is what you expect it to be.

Comment: @markerikson I have updated my question with the data coming from api server. can you take a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your update logic does not match the returned data structure from the API.

Currently, you have this initial state:

```js
const initialState = {
    category:[],
    current: null
}
```

and this logic in your `categoryReducer`:

```js
return {
  ...state,
  ..action.payload
}
```

That logic will *only* work right if `action.payload` looks like `{category: []}`.

But, you showed that the data coming back from the server looks like:

```js
[{ _id: "ksdj9dsfj", name: "monitor", description: "It is used to view what is on the system" }]
```

That is not an object, and it does not have a `category` field inside.

One fix here would be to change the reducer logic to look like:

```js
return {
  ...state,
  category: action.payload
}
```